# Autorización fallida en Google Maps

Tags: android-studio, google-maps

Alguien me puede decir porque ahora no funciona el mapa que estoy creando, al ejecutarlo no se muestra el mapa, pero si este mensaje:

Me muestra este mensaje:

```
2019-02-19 20:59:37.425 19089-19290/com.CirDocu.CirDocu E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
2019-02-19 20:59:37.455 19089-19290/com.CirDocu.CirDocu E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
    API Key: xxxxxxApJYiQ-rQBPqSlxxxx4Dh-zTxxxxx5XxY
    Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;com.CirDocu.CirDocu
```

**AndoridManifes.xml**

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

¿Porque ha pasado, y que hay que hacer para que vuelva a funcionar?

Gracias.

Comment: has creado tu API key? la tienes en tu manufest?

Comment: Si, primero realizo las pruebas en un proyecto de pruebas, y cuando funciona esos mismos pasos los realizo en el proyecto final, en el de pruebas funciona sin problemas, con otra Key claro, en cambio con el otro, muestra ese mensaje y en mapa sale sin nada, blanco.

Comment: en la misma maquina?

Comment: si, uno funciona y el otro no, incluso he generado una nueva key, y tampoco

Comment: pon la estructura de donde llmas la API Key en tu manifest

Comment: añadida en el post principal, igual que esta en el proyecto de pruebas

Comment: has la prueba poniendo el valor de la API key en lugar de `@string/google_maps_key`

Comment: Nada, pasa lo mismo,

Comment: He eliminado el comentario anterior que te dacia que había creado una nueva clave y seguía pasando lo mismo, pero me he dado cuenta que al crear la key he visto que colocaba la Restricciones a Android, lo he dejado en "Ninguna" y ahora ya funciona, no se porque se mostraba marcada esa opcion.